# How to add items to a Row object

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to add row list. First click add button it working fine.. Refer this image

[image]

And second click add button it row become double.. refer this bellow image

[image]

Pic #1 is what it is
[image]

pic #2 is what I need
[image]

how to fix just to allow one row per table

**reference code**

```
 Container(
        width: 650,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 15),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            child: Table(
                defaultColumnWidth:
                FixedColumnWidth(data.size.width * 0.1 * 8),
                // border:
                //     TableBorder.all(width: 1.0, color: Colors.grey[500]),
                children: [
                    ...this.rowList.map((row) {
                        return TableRow(children: [
                            Container(
                                child: Column(children: [
                                    Container(
                                        width: 150.0,
                                        height: 40.0,
                                        child: Text(
                                            "Serial Number",
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                        ),
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                        width: 400.0,
                                        height: 30.0,
                                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15),
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            color: Colors.grey[200],
                                            borderRadius:
                                            new BorderRadius.circular(2.0)),
                                        child: Padding(
                                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                left: 15,
                                                right: 5,
                                                top: 2,
                                                bottom: 2),
                                            child: TextFormField(
                                                initialValue: row['serialNo'],
                                                onChanged: (value) {
                                                    row['serialNo'] = value;
                                                    print(row['serialNo']);
                                                    updateDetails();
                                                },
                                                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                                    border: InputBorder.none,
                                                ),
                                            )),
                                    ),
                                    Container(
                                        width: 600.0,
                                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 1),
                                        child: Scrollbar(
                                            isAlwaysShown: true,
                                            child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                                child: Row(children: [
                                                    Column(children: [
                                                        Container(
                                                            child: Center(
                                                                child: Text('1',
                                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                                        color: Colors
                                                                        .white))),
                                                            height: 40,
                                                            width: 240.0,
                                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                                border: Border.all(
                                                                    width: 1.0,
                                                                    color: Colors.grey),
                                                                color:
                                                                Colors.grey[600])),
                                                        Table(
                                                            defaultColumnWidth:
                                                            FixedColumnWidth(
                                                                data.size.width *
                                                                0.1),
                                                            border: TableBorder.all(
                                                                width: 1.0,
                                                                color:
                                                                Colors.grey[500]),
                                                            children: [
                                                                TableRow(
                                                                    children: [
                                                                        "A",
                                                                        "B",
                                                                        "C",
                                                                        "D"
                                                                    ]
                                                                    .map((label) =>
                                                                        Container(
                                                                            height:
                                                                            40,
                                                                            color: Colors
                                                                            .black,
                                                                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                                                vertical:
                                                                                4),
                                                                            child: Center(
                                                                                child: Text(
                                                                                    label,
                                                                                    textAlign:
                                                                                    TextAlign.center,
                                                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                                                        color:
                                                                                        Colors.white),
                                                                                ))))
                                                                    .toList()),
                                                                ...this
                                                                .rowList
                                                                .map((row) {
                                                                    return TableRow(
                                                                        children: [
                                                                            'valueA',
                                                                            'valueB',
                                                                            'valueC',
                                                                            'valueD'
                                                                        ]
                                                                        .map((label) => Container(
                                                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
                                                                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4),
                                                                            child: TextFormField(
                                                                                initialValue: row['1'][label],
                                                                                onChanged: (value) {
                                                                                    row['1'][label] =
                                                                                        value;
                                                                                    print(
                                                                                        row);
                                                                                    print(
                                                                                        row['1']);
                                                                                    updateDetails();
                                                                                },
                                                                                cursorColor: Colors.grey,
                                                                                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                                                                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                                                                                    border:
                                                                                    InputBorder.none,
                                                                                    focusedBorder:
                                                                                    InputBorder.none,
                                                                                    enabledBorder:
                                                                                    InputBorder.none,
                                                                                    errorBorder:
                                                                                    InputBorder.none,
                                                                                    disabledBorder:
                                                                                    InputBorder.none,
                                                                                    isDense:
                                                                                    true,
                                                                                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                                                        horizontal: 4,
                                                                                        vertical: 4),
                                                                                ),
                                                                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: data.size.width * 0.016))))
                                                                        .toList());
                                                                }).toList()
                                                            ])
                                                    ]),
                                                ])
                                                //row
                                                // ])
                                            ))),
                                ]),
                                // ]),
                            ), //add here
                        ]);
                    }).toList()
                ]))),
Container(
    // add button
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2.0),
        color: Colors.grey[200],
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey[500], width: 1.5)),
    height: data.size.width * 0.039,
    child: FlatButton(
        onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
                Map < String, dynamic > rowValue = Map < String, dynamic > ();
                rowValue['serialNo'] = '';
                rowValue['1'] = Map < String, String > ();
                rowValue['1']['valueA'] = '';
                rowValue['1']['valueB'] = '';
                rowValue['1']['valueC'] = '';
                rowValue['1']['valueD'] = '';


                this.rowList.add(rowValue);
            });
        },
        child: Text('+ Add Box',
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.grey[900],
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: data.size.width * 0.019))),
),
```

Hopefully somebody can teach me how to fix it..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would love to help but I don't completely understand your question. Are you saying you want the "Add Box" button to add a box at the end of the current row instead of adding a new row?

Comment: I using **Add Box** to easy understand between add row table and add table row with table inside.. every time I click add box it will add Serial number and table with header example **pic #2** and the problem it add row too example **pic #1**

Comment: So the "Add Box" button should add a new table with one empty row?

Comment: true... but it have `TextFormField` for user can fill

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this example.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// main start
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: TablePage(),
    );
  }
}
/// main end

// table data class start
class TableData {
  final String serialNo;
  final List<Map<String, String>> rowData;
  TableData({
    required this.serialNo,
    required this.rowData,
  });
}
/// table data class end

// custom table start
class CustomTable extends StatefulWidget {
  final int tableId;
  final Map<String, dynamic> row;
  const CustomTable({
    super.key,
    required this.tableId,
    required this.row,
  });

  @override
  State<CustomTable> createState() => _CustomTableState();
}

class _CustomTableState extends State<CustomTable> {
  final columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: 400,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey),
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                '${widget.tableId}',
                style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Table(
            children: [
              TableRow(
                  children: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'].map((label) {
                return Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    label,
                    style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                );
              }).toList()),
              TableRow(
                children: List.generate(columns.length, (index) {
                  return DecoratedBox(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
                    ),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
/// custom table end

// custom widget start
class CustomWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final TableData tableData;
  const CustomWidget({
    super.key,
    required this.tableData,
  });

  @override
  State<CustomWidget> createState() => _CustomWidgetState();
}

class _CustomWidgetState extends State<CustomWidget> {
  ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        const Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
          child: Text('Serial Number'),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 300,
          child: TextFormField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              filled: true,
              fillColor: Colors.grey[300],
              isDense: true,
              border: InputBorder.none,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 16,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 160,
          child: Scrollbar(
            controller: scrollController,
            thumbVisibility: true,
            child: ListView.builder(
              controller: scrollController,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: widget.tableData.rowData.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return CustomTable(
                  tableId: index,
                  row: widget.tableData.rowData[index],
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

/// custom widget end

// table page start
class TablePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TablePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<TablePage> createState() => _TablePageState();
}

class _TablePageState extends State<TablePage> {
  List<TableData> tableDataList = [
    TableData(
      serialNo: '1',
      rowData: [
        {
          'valueA': '',
          'valueB': '',
          'valueC': '',
          'valueD': '',
        }
      ],
    )
  ];

  addRowToTableData(
    List<TableData> tableDataList,
    String serialNo,
    Map<String, String> rowData,
  ) {
    final tableData = tableDataList.firstWhere((element) {
      return element.serialNo == serialNo;
    });

    tableData.rowData.add(rowData);
  }

  addTableToList(List<TableData> tableDataList, TableData tableData) {
    tableDataList.add(tableData);
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: tableDataList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return CustomWidget(
                  tableData: tableDataList[index],
                );
              },
            ),
            ButtonBar(
              children: [
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    TableData secondDataTable = TableData(
                      serialNo: '2',
                      rowData: [
                        {
                          'valueA': '',
                          'valueB': '',
                          'valueC': '',
                          'valueD': '',
                        }
                      ],
                    );
                    addTableToList(tableDataList, secondDataTable);
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                  child: const Text('Add Table'),
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    final row = {
                      'valueA': 'Another value',
                      'valueB': 'Bnother value',
                      'valueC': 'Cnother value',
                      'valueD': 'Dnother value',
                    };
                    addRowToTableData(tableDataList, '1', row);
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                  child: const Text('Add Row To Existing Table'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// table page end
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you repeat some times the same tables when uses map and are little harder to read, so i made you a version using PaginatedDataTable that you can customize

> Here the code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TablePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TablePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TablePage> createState() => _TablePageState();
}

class _TablePageState extends State<TablePage> {
  int rowsPerPage = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: SizedBox(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Visibility(
                    visible: rowsPerPage > 0,
                    child: _CustomTableWithPaginator(
                      rowsPerPage: rowsPerPage,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        rowsPerPage += 1;
                      });
                    },
                    child: const Text('Add'),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}

// Table
class _CustomTableWithPaginator extends StatelessWidget {
  final int rowsPerPage;
  const _CustomTableWithPaginator({Key? key, required this.rowsPerPage}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    DataTableSource data = MyData(context);
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Theme(
      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(cardColor: Colors.black),
      child: PaginatedDataTable(
        source: data,
        columns: [
          DataColumn(
              label: Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Container(
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border(right: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey)),
                ),
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: const Text('A')),
          )),
          DataColumn(
              label: Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Container(
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border(right: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey)),
                ),
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: const Text('B')),
          )),
          // DataColumn(label: Text('Name')),
          DataColumn(
            label: Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Container(
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border(right: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey)),
                ),
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: const Text('C'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          DataColumn(
            label: Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Container(
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border(right: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey)),
                ),
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: const Text('D'),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
        columnSpacing: size.width * 0.1,
        horizontalMargin: 10,
        rowsPerPage: rowsPerPage,
        showCheckboxColumn: false,
      ),
    );
  }
}

// The "soruce" of the table
class MyData extends DataTableSource {
  // Generate some made-up data
  final BuildContext context;

  late final List<int> _data;

  MyData(this.context) {
    _data = listGeenerate();
  }

  @override
  bool get isRowCountApproximate => false;
  @override
  int get rowCount => _data.length;
  @override
  int get selectedRowCount => 0;
  @override
  DataRow getRow(int index) {
    return DataRow(
        color: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith(
            (states) => index % 2 == 0 ? const Color(0xFFF7F3F3) : const Color(0xFFeaeaea)),
        cells: [
          DataCell(Container(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                border: Border(right: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey)),
              ),
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
              child: const Text(''))),
          DataCell(Container(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                border: Border(right: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey)),
              ),
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
              child: const Text(''))),
          DataCell(Container(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                border: Border(right: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey)),
              ),
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
              child: const Text(''))),
          DataCell(Container(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                border: Border(right: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey)),
              ),
              alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
              child: const Text(''))),
        ]);
  }

  List<int> listGeenerate() {
    List<int> data = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      data.add(i);
    }

    return data;
  }
}
```

> Here you can see it in action
> https://dartpad.dev/?id=063d4bfd08e7d364652485db4076e398

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it just not allow add more table not row per table.. you can refer image in my question